# ios - Where to hook up outlets in UIViewController subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I subclassed `UIViewController` (let's call it `ParentViewController`) and added a bunch of properties and methods -- IBOutlets and IBActions and such -- that I want to subclass for `ChildViewControllerA`, `ChildViewControllerB`, `ChildViewControllerC`, etc.

My stupid question is, since all of these properties are defined in `ParentViewController's` interface, how do I hook them up in the `ChildViewControllers`' interfaces?  In my ios 7 storyboard main file, I have a ViewController for each one of `ChildViewControllerA`, `ChildViewControllerB`, ChildViewControllerC, etc. but I don't have the little plus-sign ports in their corresponding .h/.m files because they are all in `ParentViewController.h`.

Is there something I'm missing?  Do I need to redefine the properties in each `ChildViewController` in order to have some place to hook them up to their corresponding storyboard views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in the manner your described; as I just verified.

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;
@end
```

Create subclasses of `ParentViewController` and set the custom classes in the Storyboard editor to `ChildViewControllerA` and `ChildViewControllerB`, like so:

[image]

The outlets should be there if this corresponds to what you're doing.

[image]

In short, you should not need to redefine outlets that are defined earlier in the object hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the clear screenshot!  This may be unrelated, but for some reason the UIImageViews that I hooked up (between the nib for ChildViewControllerA and ChildViewControllerA.h) aren't appearing.. In the debugger, the variable for the UIImage and UILabels appear to be not changing even though I am setting (UILabel*)propA.text = *newString*. It's defaulting to whatever is in the nib, when before I subclassed it was overwriting what was in the nib.

Comment: Not sure, what's going on there without seeing the code context.  Any chance you're making these changes before the outlets are loaded?  You could implement `awakeFromNib` and see.

Comment: Added "self." before the property names as such, (UILabel*)self.propA.text = newString, and that solved it.  On a more related note, what is mildly concerning is that even in ParentViewController, the properties appear to be hooked up, but as I create more ChildViewControllers, the properties as defined in ParentViewController can't possibly be hooked up to all of the nib views, can they?

Comment: Good catch. If I'm understanding your question correctly, `ParentViewController` is essentially an abstract superclass of a group of classes that you instantiate via loading a Storyboard.  The outlet connections are specific to each child; and you'll make them 1-by-1 in the editor.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You understood correctly!  Thank you.  "1-by-1 in the editor" makes perfect sense, with 1 being the customized nib for each ChildViewController, but the other 1 being the outlet from the ChildViewController .h file... or from your graphic?  The graphic from your screenshot seems to suggest that I don't need a corresponding property definition in the ChildViewController.h file, that if the "Custom Class" name is entered properly for the individual ChildViewController UIVC nibs, registration is automatic, even if not visible from the child .h file alone (there not being definitions).  Correct?

Answer (score 0):

What do you try to do? If you try to pass parameters to another view controller, use this method in your ParentViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     [segue.destinationViewController yourInitializationMethod:withProperties];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is quite simple, if you inherit any class the Outlets will be available to all the other classes which inherits it. For eg.

In your case you have `Parent` and in it you have Outlet say a `ButtonA`. Now other classes `Child1` and `Child2` inherits `Parent` they can access `ButtonsA`, but if you create any outlet to `Child1` and `Child2` and if no other class inherits it, it wont be available for any, and it wont be available for `Parent` as well.. If you want to access the properties you can have the `Child Controller` as a property in any one of your class.

Hope this helps.